# Simplifying constants

Tags: simplify, maxima

In the expressions below, *x* is variable and *a*, *b*, *c*, *k* are undefined constants. Is there a function to *simplify* constants in Maxima?

Examples,

- x^2 - 2a + b + c becomes x^2 + k
- 2^x + a/b + c^2 become 2^x + k

Answer (score 3):

There is not a specific function for it, but I think you can create something via `freeof`. E.g.:

```
(%i12) merge_constants (expr, var, newconst) :=
         block ([freeof_var : sublist (args (expr), lambda ([e1], freeof (var, e1)))],
           expr - apply ("+", freeof_var) + newconst) $
(%i13) merge_constants (x^2 - 2*a + b + c, x, k);
                                     2
(%o13)                              x  + k
(%i14) merge_constants (2^x + a/b + c^2, x, k);
                                     x
(%o14)                              2  + k
(%i15) merge_constants (sin(u) + u*cos(v) + v^2 + tan(w), u, m);
(%o15)                       u cos(v) + sin(u) + m
```

This function `merge_constants` is just a first try. I'm sure there are ways to improve it. E.g. return the `freeof_var` value to see what was replaced by `newconst`. Anyway I hope this is useful.

Comment: Reviving the topic, actually there is to a certain extent. Expand the expression in additive terms, split the formula into two bags B1 and B2 so as B1 containing x and B2 other containing remaining terms, then exchange B for a new unknown variable, say alpha. Solution is alpha plus sum of terms in B1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this sort of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60977954/1089161). (I'm not sure if that answer should be duplicated here and that issue closed as a duplicate of this or if this should just reference that.)