# Is there a way to handle constant function parameters in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am generating symbolic functions and using SymPy to simplify them. 
Now I would like a way to "simplify" symbols that represent constant parameters in a function that is yet to be fitted.
For example, if I am generating a polynomial, I might generate a string like this

```
C*x*x + C*x + C*x + C,
```

which SymPy would turn into

```
C*x^2 + 2*C*x + C.
```

Now I would like to find a way to get this:

```
C*x^2 + C*x + C.
```

In other words, is there a way to tell SymPy that a certain symbol is constant and undefined, so that

```
C+C -> C, C*C -> C, etc. Or more generally: f(C) = C, for any f(C)?
```

My first idea was that perhaps there is an assumption (such as Q.positive) that describes this property and I might be able to use refine. However, this does not seem to be the case.
If nothing else, I'm sure there is a way to use preorder_traversal to do what I want, but I can't come up with a strategy to do it.
Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean for the symbol C to be the same symbol in each term? If so then it should you would need to replace `C` with `C/2` in the other terms as well.

Comment: cf https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (applied to an expression that has been fully expanded):

```
def consim(eq, *v):
    con = numbered_symbols('c', cls=Dummy)
    reps = {}
    for i in preorder_traversal(eq):
        if i.is_Mul or i.is_Add:
            c, d = i.as_independent(*v)
            if c != i.identity and c.free_symbols:
                c = reps.setdefault(c, next(con))
    return eq.subs(reps)


>>> from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, x
>>> eq = 2*a*x**2 + b*c*x + d + e
>>> consim(eq, x)
         2
c₀ + c₁⋅x  + c₂⋅x
```

You probably want numbered symbols, not all symbols the same.

Comment: Wow! I only partially understand what is happening in your code, but it works!
However, I have an issue. It appears that for the case of sums or multiplications of a free constant, the numbering goes wild. In your example, if we set e=d, the return is:
c0 + c2*x**2 + c3*x. Looking at the constants the function assembles, it counts c0 twice. Can you please look into this?

Furthermore, it seems to me that this should not work for multivariate functions. At yet it seems to work when I test it. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the numbering will be arbitrary. Polynomials could be renumbered in order of degree of the monomial. It should work for multivariate functions as long as you pass all variables after the expression, e.g. `consim(eq, x, y)`. This is only a lightweight routine, e.g. it doesn't check too deeply for interdependent constants.